# How to Pass memory bit and data register in PLC communications

Tags: python, modbus, plc, rs485

I tried to setup communication with Modbus RTU protocol between PLC and python using the pymodbus library. The communication protocol settings are as follows.

Required Parameters:

- Data Format of communication : RTU.
- Data length: 8.(this is constant)
- Parity: None.
- Stopbit: 1.
- Baudrate: 9600.
- TimeOut: 0
- Station Address: 1
- DataRegister: D0.....D100.
- Memory Bit: M1...M100.

```py
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
client = ModbusSerialClient(method = "rtu", port = "COM5", stopbits = 1, bytesize=8, parity = "N", baudrate = 9600)
client.connect()
result_ = client.read_holding_registers(address=0x1017, count=2, unit=1)
result_.registers
_result = client.write_registers(0x1017, 445, unit =1)
print(_result)
```

I was not able to read the particular holding register or write to a register. Is there some other way to setup communication between PLC and Pymodbus.

Comment: Hello Pandurang, and welcome to SO. Can you please add to your question the error you are getting? Are you sure of the addresses of the registers you are trying to read and/or write? If not maybe you can mention the brand of the PLC and point to a document that explain its Modbus map. What you are trying to do should be pretty straightforward software wise; oftentimes the problem is coming from hardware malfunctioning or wiring and grounding issues, so maybe you can elaborate on those.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.